# Run PHP code inside HTML file - Prevent page from downloading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to run **PHP** code in **HTML** file (i know it is not a perfect solution but it has to be this way). I know that this needs to be added in **.htaccess** file in order to run PHP inside HTML file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

But wen i do this, and wen i try to open my page, browser just automatically downloads the page... I have no idea why.

I also tryed this but no luck:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

My website is on Apache server. Please help me if you know the solution

Comment: Why does it have to be a HTML file?

Comment: you don't need to .htaccess to run php inside html ! just open and close php tags inside the html file `<?php echo "hi"; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also to set the correct handler to the file extension:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|htm|html)$"> 
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php 
</FilesMatch>
```

I would also recommend not to modify the already defined type of an extension since what you want is to preprocess the html file not to change its mime.